# Run code only once in entire Windows Forms Application Lifetime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a Windows Forms Application using Visual Studio 2010 IDE. My need is that I have certain block of code that needs to be run only once, at the starting of the application and never again for the entire lifetime(by lifetime I mean never again on the same system,unless the system is reconfigured). I have placed that code in a separate `.cs` file and for now, I run it's assembly(`.exe`) manually for testing purposes. But for deployment purposes, how do I go about it? It contains code for creating scheduled tasks using the `schtasks` command through command prompt. I know there are workarounds for the same, but I need to stick to the `schtasks` approach. I know there is something like `Setup Projects` that help us configure all the files that are required for the installation of our project and also create an installation file in the end, but can I write some code in it to ensure that it runs once, during installation, before my application is executed?

Comment: A Singleton Pattern , creates only one instance throught the application ,also its thread safe. Try implementing that pattern. This is an Idea not a solution. If u can paste the code, we would come up with some idea!

Comment: @madhairsilence: Singleton Pattern is useless here. The OP doesn't want to create a single instance. The OP wan't to execute some routine once on a system and then never again (unless the system is reconfigured).

Comment: What does creating an instance mean. calling a constructor. Cant he place a code in the constructor, make it private, instantiate the static variable inline??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can have a Setup and Deployment package run an exe during installation. You will have to create a Custom Action in the setup to do that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on it a bit? Maybe a link? I think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx) [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects) - just Google "visual studio setup and deployment custom action".